# Chainlink node not connecting to External Adapter

Tags: oracles, external-api, chainlink

I'm trying to use the [Chainlink External Adapter to connect my contract to Twitter](https://market.link/adapters/9ebb251e-1d7c-433d-9835-d771996f5b9c) but my node I'm running is seemingly not able to connect to the adapter at localhost:8080 even though the adapter says that's the port it's listening on. Specifically I'm getting the error, `ExternalBridge post to external adapter: connection refused`. Thoughts?

[image: chainlink external adapter not connecting]

Comment: Is your chainlink node and database also running locally? Can you call the EA from a `curl` command?

Comment: Yes, node, database, and adapter are currently all on the same machine. As I'm typing this though I'm realizing the node and database are each in their own docker container with their own IP which might be the issue. EA is running natively, no container. Localhost in the node container is not localhost of my native OS. When I run your example curl command, it works and the test Tweet is posted.

Comment: Changed the Bridge spec in my Chainlink node from localhost to my machine's 192.168.1.X local IP and that fixed it. Thanks for the assist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the Bridge spec in my Chainlink node from localhost to my machine's 192.168.1.X local IP and that fixed it. Issue was my node was running in a docker container but the adapter was running on my native OS. So localhost from my node's perspective is not localhost from the adapter's perspective.

FYI: Can find your specific local IP by running "ip addr" on Linux and it will be the IP of your main interface, such as eth0. Can also see the docker IP this way.

Comment: This is great! How did you find that 192.168.1.X? Could you update your answer with that?

Comment: Sure, adding that to the answer now.